# Unable to connect to Bluetooth LE device, DevicePairingResultStatus.Failed

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, phonegap-plugins

I am creating a cross-platform app to interface with a Bluetooth LE device. The app works on Android and iOS, but fails to connect on Windows. When I call `pairAsync()`, the "connecting" window pops up for a bit, then changes to "Connection failed". The returned status is 19, `DevicePairingResultStatus.Failed`, "An unknown failure occurred." according to the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicepairingresultstatus).

I am using [cordova-plugin-bluetoothle](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) to handle cross-platform differences. I have tried on multiple computers with builtin and USB Bluetooth adapters.

Connection code:

```
connect: function (successCallback, errorCallback, params) {
    if (!initialized) {
        errorCallback({ error: "connect", message: "Not initialized." });
        return;
    }

    var address = params && params[0] && params[0].address;
    if (!address) {
        errorCallback({ error: "connect", message: "Device address is not specified" });
        return;
    }

    var DeviceInformation = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation;
    var DeviceInformationKind = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationKind;

    WinJS.Promise.wrap(address)
    .then(function (deviceAddress) {
        // If we have cached device info return it right now
        if (WATCH_CACHE[deviceAddress]) return [WATCH_CACHE[deviceAddress]];
        // Otherwise try to search it again
        var selector = "System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{bb7bb05e-5972-42b5-94fc-76eaa7084d49}\" AND " +
                                        "System.Devices.Aep.ContainerId:=\"{" + deviceAddress + "}\" AND " +
                                        "(System.Devices.Aep.CanPair:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True OR " +
                                        "System.Devices.Aep.IsPaired:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True)";
        return DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(selector, ["System.Devices.Aep.ContainerId"], DeviceInformationKind.associationEndpoint);
    })
    .then(function (devices) {
        return Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice.fromIdAsync(devices[0].id);
    })
    .then(function (bleDevice) {
        var DevicePairingProtectionLevel = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DevicePairingProtectionLevel;
        var DevicePairingResultStatus = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DevicePairingResultStatus;
        var DevicePairingKinds = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DevicePairingKinds;

        if (bleDevice.deviceInformation.pairing.isPaired) {
            return bleDevice;
        }

        if (!bleDevice.deviceInformation.pairing.canPair) {
            throw { error: "connect", message: "The device does not support pairing" };
        }

        // TODO: investigate if it is possible to pair without user prompt
        return bleDevice.deviceInformation.pairing.pairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.none)
        .then(function (res) {
            if (res.status === DevicePairingResultStatus.paired ||
                    res.status === DevicePairingResultStatus.alreadyPaired)
                return bleDevice;

                // I modified these two lines to return the actual error message instead of a generic rejection message
                var msg = getDevicePairingResultStatusMessage(res.status);
                throw { error: "connect", message: "(" + res.status + ") " + msg };
        });
    })
    .done(function (bleDevice) {
        var result = {
            name: bleDevice.deviceInformation.name,
            address: address,
            status: "connected"
        };

        // Attach listener to device to report disconnected event
        bleDevice.addEventListener('connectionstatuschanged', function connectionStatusListener(e) {
            if (e.target.connectionStatus === Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionStatus.disconnected) {
                result.status = "disconnected";
                successCallback(result);
                bleDevice.removeEventListener('connectionstatuschanged', connectionStatusListener);
            }
        });

        // Need to use keepCallback to be able to report "disconnect" event
        // https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#connect
        successCallback(result, { keepCallback: true });
    }, function (err) {
        errorCallback(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bleDevice.deviceInformation.pairing.**Custom**.Pairasync

```
private async void deviceListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ClickedItem as DeviceInformation;
    if (item.Pairing.CanPair)
    {
        var customPairing = item.Pairing.Custom;
        customPairing.PairingRequested += CustomPairing_PairingRequested;
        var result = await customPairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ProvidePin);
        customPairing.PairingRequested -= CustomPairing_PairingRequested;
        if ((result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.Paired) ||
            (result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.AlreadyPaired))
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DevicePage), item);
        }
    }
    else if (item.Pairing.IsPaired == true)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DevicePage), item);
    }
}

private void CustomPairing_PairingRequested(DeviceInformationCustomPairing sender, DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Accept("123456");
}
```

Comment: I've also tried `return bleDevice.deviceInformation.pairing.custom.pairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.confirmOnly, DevicePairingProtectionLevel.none)
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }, function (res) {
                console.error(res);
            });` and get the same 19 status code

Comment: You also have to set custom pairing event handler. See update in my answer

Comment: Tried `bleDevice.deviceInformation.pairing.custom.addEventListener("pairingrequested", function (a) { a.accept();  });` but the event is never called. I do see the native popup asking if I want to connect to the device.

Comment: You use ConfigmrOnly. What si your device and what kind of pairing does it support?

Comment: It is a custom device with only a handful of buttons and lights as IO, no screen. I'm currently testing with both a Microchip Curiosity HPC dev board and Android app emulating the Bluetooth portion of the device.

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding how Bluetooth (for this device?) works. Using the [sample from a Xamarin plugin](https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle) I'm able to connect and read/write, but pairing fails. For some reason the cordova plugin on Windows tries to pair instead of just connect, while the Android and iOS versions can connect fine.

Comment: I am not sure about pluging but WinRT API you use there also allows to just connect without pairing.try to use DevicePairingKinds_None. I also faced the issue with pairing when try to connect to BLE emulator that runs on Android smartphone (cause smartphone itself needs to be paired).

Comment: Just tried switching to `bleDevice.deviceInformation.pairing.custom.pairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.none, DevicePairingProtectionLevel.none)` and it completes immediately with the same status (19) instead of the several seconds after hitting "Yes" that `confirmOnly` takes

Comment: Ping me by skype (mike.petrichenko) we'll try to solve it. It should be faster than these comments.